# Perl WWW::Mechanize using Proxy, cannot submit form

Tags: perl, proxy, www-mechanize

when using WWW::Mechanize and a proxy everything works fine. However, when fetching a form and submit post data, by using the proxy it won't work (timeout). Without proxy everything works fine.
I got this kind of code:

```
    $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1, timeout => 3 );             
    $browser->proxy('http','http://127.0.0.1:8118');    
    $browser->proxy('https','https://127.0.0.1:8118');                                      
    $browser->get("http://someurl.com");        

    if ( $browser->success() ) {

        $browser->form_name('form');

        $browser->field('a', 1);
        $browser->field('b', 2);

        $browser->field('c', 3);

        # won't submit using proxy
        $browser->submit();

  }
```

Does anybody got an solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of details for the URL of the form target I will guess that this is https while the origin of the form was simple http. First be aware that while LWP (the library underlying WWW::Mechanize) supports a proxy to handle forwarding of https connections it probably does not support proxies which gets accessed by https themselves. But given that you use the same IP:port for http and https proxy my assumption is that you've simply made it typo and it must be like this:

```
$browser->proxy('http', 'http://127.0.0.1:8118');    
$browser->proxy('https','http://127.0.0.1:8118');
```

Apart from that make sure that the version of LWP you are using is at least 6.06 because earlier versions did had bugs in properly handling https connections when a proxy was configured.

Comment: It is all http, also the submitting etc. I also tried your solution, same result :(
It looks like that the script just won't submit at all when using a proxy.

Comment: @JOhnlw009a: The script by itself shows no obvious problems apart from the https proxy. Unfortunately the information you currently provide makes it impossible to reproduce the problem. I would recommend that you provide a minimal example to reproduce it. Since you claim that nothing is done with https then you could also eliminate the setting of the https proxy.

Comment: I did eliminate it and tracked eveyrthing, it is all really http only. I tested it on a couple servers where TOR/Privoxy is installed. Firewall is also off. The problem would occur for all forms I guess.